# Is there a way to make Alfred press 'Enter' key after workflow is done?

Tags: mac, alfred

I have a simple **workflow** that I call on pressing **CMD+D**. It just calls **Alfred** and puts "`define word_from_clipboard`" in the search box. Then I have to press enter to run it. Is there a way to automate it - so I don't have to press '**Enter**' key to see the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to adjust your workflow. I'm using this myself to define the OS X text selection (instead of the clipboard) and I get the definitions shown right away.

Try to configure or recreate your workflow this way:

`Triggers > Hotkey` with `Action: Show Alfred`, `Argument: OS X Clipboard contents`, `Prefix: define` (include a white space after define)

If you were referring to open the dictionary right away, without showing the results in Alfred and having to press enter to view the definition on the Dictionary app, then you could do:

`Triggers > Hotkey` with `Action: Pass through to workflow`, `Argument: OS X Clipboard contents`, `Prefix:` (leave it empty)

Add and connect an `Actions > Run script` module with this content: `open dict://"{query}"`

Comment: Aaaaah, thank you very much, you're the man. It does work flawlessly, again thank you man.

Answer (score 2):

In case we do not want to use Alfred to look the meaning of words, we can use a built-in dictionary and assign a key combo for that.

## Mac System Preference

```
Click on the top left Apple icon and open System preference
Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
Then assign keys cmd-control-d for the dictionary lookup
```

[image]

## **Usage**

We can just select any word (double-click it), then press cmd-ctrl-d, it will open dictionary app and show the meaning instantly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @Toto I have updated the answer.

Comment: @astro123 +1 thank you very much for your help.